# Why `1 > undefined` evaluates to false?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make some conditional statements while trying to solve a coding challenge. I have kept track of all the occurrences of letters of two strings in different objects. When I try to compare them by their counts if the count is undefined in the other object it evaluates to false even though the first value is truthy.

However;

`1 > Boolean(undefined)` evaluates to true. However 1 > undefined evaluates to false. Is there reason why the behavior is so ?

Comment: Why don't you console log `Boolean(undefined)`?

Comment: @trincot It evaluates to false. In that case 1 > Boolean(undefined) evaluates to true.

Comment: And that surprises you? In many programming languages false is considered as 0 when compared with numbers.

Comment: It surprises me that 1 > undefined evaluates to false.

Comment: If your question is about `1 > undefined` why do you state it as `1 > Boolean(undefined)`?

Comment: The title of the question does state that. I wanted to make a comparison of both cases to know why the behavior differs. If you think this can be improved to clarify the question please kindly edit the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript does a lot of funky casting when you compare things together that usually shouldn't be comparable.

`1>undefined` casts undefined to a NaN, and you can't compare a number to a Not a Number so any comparison will return false `>`,`<`,`==` etc

When you do `1>Boolean(undefined)` undefined is cast to its boolean `equivalent` false, then when it's compared it will be cast to a 0, you can confirm this by doing `Number(Boolean(undefined))` and since 1 is bigger than 0 it returns true.

Answer (score 2):

In order to use the comparison operator `>`, both operands must be numeric. `1` already is, so `Boolean(undefined)` (which evaluates to `false` by the way) must be converted to a number. When it is, you get `0`.

```js
// First, convert undefined to a Boolean
let bool = Boolean(undefined)
console.log(bool);

// Then convert that to a number
let num = Number(bool);
console.log(num);
```

So, `1 > 0` is `true`.

**Things to understand:**

JavaScript is a ["loosely" or "weakly" typed language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_and_weak_typing). This means that data can, and often is, implicitly converted (coerced) into a different type category.

All data can be classified as ["truthy"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) or ["falsy"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/falsy), which means that if converted to a Boolean, would it convert to `true` or `false`. Things like `null`, `undefined`, `""`, `0`, `false`, and `NaN` are all "falsy". And `false` in JavaScript (and most other languages) converts to the number `0`, while `true` usually converts to `1`.